# WPF loading grid child based on treeview click

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm developing a WPF C# app where I have a tree view control and if the user clicks on a node in the tree, a node-specific detail 'form' appears in a named Grid somewhere else in the form.  If you click on a different node in the tree, the displayed detail form checks if the contents are saved, is dismissed, and a new detail form appears in it's place.

What I need is some starting advice.  Can I still implement the forms as standalone xaml, then put some some of 'container' in the grid that I throw the form into as a child?  Or just add the form as a grid child somehow.  How do I programmatically load the form I want in the grid and communicate with it?

Thanks for any assistance!
Corey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event aggregator design pattern, see here for details:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html

You can then have some other code which listens for the node change clicks via the event aggregator and response accordingly. This will decouple your code and make it more testable.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you are using mvvm?
If not read up on it - will make it easier.

then you have your form with the treeview on it, bound to its itemsource on the view model.
Usually an items control like a treeview will have a selecteditem property on it.
Bind that to a property on your viewmodel which is of the type of objects contained in your treeview. Call this for example CurrentlySelectedItem.

Your details 'form' can be a control or whatever you want on the same form.
Now depending on how complete your object is - you have at least two options. If your object in the treeview has all the data you need already, then just bind the details to CurrentlySelectedItem.

Obviously it must implement INotifyPropertyChanged to tell the binding system to update the values.

If the object doesn't have enough info, then on the setter of CurrentlySelectedItem you can then fire a method to load the full object and then bind the details to that full object.

Alternativley, another popular approach, you could have the details form as a self contained control that subscribes to a message and when it recieves the message with the key of the treeview object, it loads the required info.